# Show in webpart a list of the titles of all lists from contenttype X?

Tags: list, content-type

I would like to add a webpart to my page with all the Titles of all my lists from contenttype X. How can I implement this?

For example I have 4 lists which are using contenttype X:

```
ListA
ListB
ListC
ListD
```

In my webpart I would like to have all these list instances with some a  href to the list:

```
ListA
ListB
ListC
ListD
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `SPContentTypeUsage.GetUsages` method to get the list instances where a content type has been used. Example:

```
SPContentType ct = site.RootWeb.ContentTypes["ContentType"];
IList<SPContentTypeUsage> usages = SPContentTypeUsage.GetUsages(ct);
foreach (SPContentTypeUsage usage in usages)
{
    if (usage.IsUrlToList)
    {
        SPList list = web.GetList(usage.Url);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution programmatically. I am looking for some solution OOTB or in SharePoint designer.